# Python Code building - replacing column data in excel

Tags: python

I am trying to build the `python` code. I used to `R` but now I need to build codes in `python` and need help :)

Conditions/situations :

1. one or more different excel files exist. They have the same column header names.
2. Select some column data from file #1 and other column data frim file #2 (for example if there are 2 files to play with).
3. I want to replace these selected column data with final excel file columns data
4. Then, want the replaced file to be save as csv file

Additional question,
In developing codes, how can I be flexible to choose one or more columns to replace?
If you guys have suggestions, please share with me !

Thank you !

Comment: Use NumPy and this should help you do everything you want to.

Comment: [`pandas`[(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html) is the module you need. Load the files with `pd.read_excel` and you can process the columns as you please, then save with `pd.to_csv`